# How to calculate small and wide-angle X-ray scattering spectra for the hydration shell restricted by a distance radius criteria

Tags: molecular-dynamics, spectroscopy, x-ray-diffraction, water, solvation

My main aim is to extract the SWAXS spectra for the hydration shell surrounding a solvated molecule and I am unfamiliar with the idea of excluded solvent volume. I tried looking online but many articles did not elaborate on the process of setting up such a calculation, or directly used an online server for those results.

In my case I have a single large solute molecule fixed and frozen at the center of the simulation box and I can calculate the SWAXS spectra of the entire simulation system using the xyz coordinates. Using this a stepping point, how can I go about calculating the SWAXS spectra for the hydration shell defined by distance cutoff criteria?

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but just came back to see how things were going. It's been a while and this question didn't get any comments or edits since its first hour. Do you have any update based on anything you've learned about this question since asking it?

Comment: Hi Nike, sorry i couldn't reply earlier. I was busy with some personal stuff. I haven't got any updates on this question. I thought that it would be nice to have different contribution to the total scattering spectra for different solvation layers around the solute, but I guess the required methodology might be too esoteric and/or cumbersome to be used by most people on the site.